# Avoiding subquery repetion and better performs

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to get the sum of what the customer who spent the most bought and then the sum of what all the other customers bought. I solved it by calculating the maximum for the calcSumOfPrice subquery, and then calculating the other values less than the maximum and aggregating them together, but I still wonder if there is a better way in terms of style and performance.

```
WITH calcSumOfPrice AS (
  SELECT c.cust_name, SUM(oi.quantity * oi.item_price) total_spent
        FROM Customers c
        JOIN Orders o ON c.cust_id=o.cust_id
        JOIN OrderItems oi ON oi.order_num=o.order_num
        JOIN Products p ON p.prod_id = oi.prod_id
        GROUP BY c.cust_name
)
SELECT tst.cust_name, MAX(tst.total_spent) as total_spent
FROM calcSumOfPrice as tst
GROUP BY tst.cust_name
HAVING total_spent = (
    SELECT MAX(tst.total_spent) as max_spent
    FROM calcSumOfPrice as tst
    )
UNION
SELECT 'Others' cust_name, SUM(tbm.total_spent) total_spent
FROM (
    SELECT tst.cust_name, MAX(tst.total_spent) as total_spent
    FROM calcSumOfPrice as tst
    GROUP BY tst.cust_name
    HAVING total_spent < (
        SELECT MAX(tst.total_spent) as max_spent
        FROM calcSumOfPrice as tst
    )
) tbm;
```

This is the database schema:

https://i.ibb.co/gFwv8VN/schema.jpg

Comment: Trusting that you have unique customer names seems unsafe to me.

Comment: Everyone put -1 but none tells me why and how to do it better.

Why is it unsafe?

Comment: Re: "unsafe"...  Have you never encountered someone else named "Salvio"?  (I know of another "Rick James".)

Comment: Another "unsafe" -- What if two customers each spent identical max amounts?

Comment: You're right! but how is it possible that two of them spend the same amount of money in areal shop? I only asked if I can do in a more elegant manner with join and avoiding( if possible) subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly more elegant and possibly faster.

1. Find the `cust_id` and `amt_spent` for each cust_id
2. Find the emax of that, but using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`
3. Gather the total spent by everyone.
4. Subtract from step 3 the max found in step 2.

Comment: Ca you write a query I'm just curious.